# ¿Como diferenciar formularios en JQuery?

Tags: php, mysql, jquery, ajax

tengo el siguiente problema. Estoy trayendo valores con Ajax desde una base de datos y necesito guardarlos para poder después enviarlo y guardarlo en otra base de datos. Se me ocurrió crear una función que recorra la tabla desde la que cargo los datos y que por cada valor me cree un formulario con su imput para poder desde ahi con un boton "agregar" poder seleccionar cada una que quiero ingresar. El caso es que al crear todos los formularios, sea cual sea el input que agregue siempre se envia el valor del primer formulario.

Este seria el código:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "backend/sesiontienda.php",
    type: "GET",
    success: function(respuesta) {
      let productos = JSON.parse(respuesta);
      let template = "";

      productos.forEach(producto => {
        template += `<div><form class="producto">

        <label>Nombre del producto</label>
        <input type="text" name="nombreproducto" value="${producto.nombre}">

        <label>Información</label>
        <input type="text" name="informacionproducto" value="${
          producto.informacion
        }">

        <input type="submit" value="subirproducto" class="btn">
      </form></br></div>`;
      });

      $(".listadeproductos").html(template);

      $("form").submit(function() {
        $.post(
          "backend/guardar-producto-desdetienda.php",
          {
            nombreproducto: $("input[name='nombreproducto']").val(),
            informacionproducto: $("input[name='informacionproducto']").val()
          },
          function() {
            $(".producto").each(function() {
              this.reset();
            });
          },
          "json"
        );

        $(".producto").each(function() {
          this.reset();
        });

        return false;
      });
```

Mi pregunta es si hay alguna otra forma de hacer eso. O como puedo solucionarlo.

Comment: probaste asignar los submit con un foreach? onda `$("form").each(function () { $(this).submit(function () {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

para diferenciar cada formulario puedes utilizar la el `$(this)` y luego ponerle un `.find("input[name='nombreproducto']").val();` de tal manera que se quedaría algo como esto `$(this).find("input[name='nombreproducto']").val();`

El `this` cojera el elemento que ha accionado el evento.

Recuerda que el `this` cambia conforme entras en una función por lo que te recomiendo generar una variable con el formulario como `var formulario=$(this);`

Comment: Muchas gracias! Solucionado con el $(this).find antes del input.